# Authorizing using WSO2 permissions

Tags: java, permissions, wso2, identity-management, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 seems to support 2 scenarios/models of authorization (e.g. as explained [here](http://srinathsview.blogspot.co.il/2012/05/authentication-and-authorization.html)): First is **Database based Permission Store** and the other is **XACML based authorization using defined policies**. The first allows you to define permission in a nice UI tree per each role while the later requires more complex policy definitions (but more flexible as it is fine grained permissions).

As far as I found it, those are separate mechanisms, and XACML queries does not consider the permissions defined by the first method. Since I need to support a simple RBAC model, I wish to concentrate on the first kind.

Using Java, I have found how to use the SDK to check the user decision using EntitlementServiceStub SDK, however I failed to find the SDK that can be used to **check if the user has permissions of the first kind** (I was just able to get the UI definitions, but I'm looking for something that can answer what is the decision/result, e.g. given "user1" & "/permission/protected/server-admin/homepage" can answer "true" - I suspect RemoteAuthorizationManagerServiceStub but not sure it is).

What is the SDK I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

According to the post, it claims that database permission store is only available for Carbon based Server. And I think you are trying to do the same for identity server. In the documentation, it is not mentioned which means it does not support this feature for identity server

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. Identity Server supports both permissions & XACML entitlements. You can define both in the UI. Moreover, the permissions defines the functionality users can perform in IS UI. So both are supported in IS.

Comment: Could you show me the link to the documentation where it claims that Identity server supports permission based database ?

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/API+Permissions (methods like getRolePermissions), https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Roles+and+Permissions

Comment: I apologize for misunderstanding. I thought It could provide us a way to customize they way we want to store data and provide our own implementation for Policy Decision Point. Thanks for your infor